# How do I convert from an integer to a string?

Tags: string, int, type-conversion, rust

I am unable to compile code that converts a type from an integer to a string. I'm running an example from the [Rust for Rubyists tutorial](http://www.rustforrubyists.com/book/chapter-05.html) which has various type conversions such as:

`"Fizz".to_str()` and  `num.to_str()` (where `num` is an integer).

I think the majority (if not all) of these `to_str()` function calls have been deprecated. What is the current way to convert an integer to a string?

The errors I'm getting are:

```
error: type `&'static str` does not implement any method in scope named `to_str`
error: type `int` does not implement any method in scope named `to_str`
```

Comment: sorry if I don't follow but i've tried looking up the int source and it seems to use http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/std/num/strconv/index.html but this just returns a byte vector. In addition there is the `to_string()` method but that returns `String` and not a literal string.

Comment: haha nevermind, I thought `to_str()` was a different return value, I'll use `to_string()`

Comment: @user3358302, no method can return a thing you call "literal string" unless they do return statically known literals because these values have type `&'static str`, that is, a string slice with a static lifetime, which is impossible to obtain using dynamically created data. You can only create them using string literals.

Comment: good to know! I think the method `to_str` confused me (which as you said, they renamed for clarity) thinking it was returning a string slice instead of a `String` object.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Use [`to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) ([running example here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2375c58114bc3f126d5754922578aeac&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
let x: u32 = 10;
let s: String = x.to_string();
println!("{}", s);
```

---

You're right; `to_str()` was renamed to `to_string()` before Rust 1.0 was released for consistency because an allocated string is now called [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html).

If you need to pass a string slice somewhere, you need to obtain a `&str` reference from `String`. This can be done using `&` and a deref coercion:

```
let ss: &str = &s;   // specifying type is necessary for deref coercion to fire
let ss = &s[..];     // alternatively, use slicing syntax
```

The tutorial you linked to seems to be obsolete. If you're interested in strings in Rust, you can look through [the strings chapter of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this clears things up :) Also i'll go through that tutorial since string conversion seems like something that's still changing on rust.